# How to override a function in a class being returned from module in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, overriding, factory

I have a logging class in a module which contains a static function to return an instance of itself, so a simplified version looks like this:

```js
Class Logger {

    static createFromConfig(key) {   
      return new Logger(key);
    }

    info(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }

    debug(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }

    error(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }
}
```

This is used in many places throughout our codebase like:

```js
    import logging from 'logging';
    const log = logging.Logger.createFromConfig('keyname');
    log.info('App starting');
```

In one project I wish to add some extra functionality to the error function, without having to change code in any of the places calling it. So something like

```js
log.error = () => {
    // do my extra stuff here
    log.error() // call the original error function
}
```

I've tried extending the class like below but I think the problem is the original base class just gets returned from the static function so my overridden function isn't called:

```js
class dblogger extends logging.Logger {
  error(...args) {
   // do my extra stuff here 
    super.error();
  }
}

const dblogging = {
  Logger: dblogger
};

export default dblogging;
```

Comment: Why doesn't your `Logger` class have a normal constructur instead of the `createFromConfig()` method? Then you would be able to subclass it properly.

Comment: It does actually have a constructor which takes a bunch of params, I just didn't include that in this stripped down version. I didn't write the class but this createfromConfig is basicallly looking for a config block in a config.json and using that to then call the constructor passing the params

Comment: `createFromConfig` could use `return new this(key)` so that it would work with subclasses. If you can't modify that, just don't use `createFromConfig` but create your custom subclass instance with `new` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the original method from the `Logger` prototype.

```
function getdblogger(keyname) {
    const log = logging.Logger.createFromConfig(keyname);
    log.error = function(message) {
        // do my extra stuff here
        Logger.prototype.error.call(this, message) // call the original error function
    }
    return log;
}
```

Note that you have to use an ordinary function rather than an arrow function so it gets `this`.

If you can get changes made to the original `Logger` class, you could chage `createFromConfig()` to allow the class to be specified, then you could use your subclass.

```
Class Logger {

    static createFromConfig(key, loggerClass = Logger) {   
      return new loggerClass(key);
    }

    info(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }

    debug(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }

    error(message) {
      // do logging stuff
    }
}
```

Then in your files:

```
const log = logging.Logger.createFromConfig('keyname', dblogger);
```

Comment: doesn't this mean in every file that is creating a logger instance i'll need to add this below it?

Comment: You need to do this for every instance that wants to override the `error` method.

Comment: I was hoping for a way without changing either the original module or the various files creating instances of the class, by making some kind of wrapper module maybe

Comment: You can encapsulate the above code into a function.

Comment: I've added the function.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you really want to use this`.constructor.prototype.`error within your method:

```js
class Logger{
  static createFromConfig(key){   
    return new Logger(key);
  }
  info(message){
    // do logging stuff
  }
  debug(message){
    // do logging stuff
  }
  error(message){
    return message;
    // do logging stuff
  }
}
class logging extends Logger{
}
const log = logging.createFromConfig('test');
log.error = function(message){
  console.log(this.constructor.prototype.error('Logger message here'));
  console.log(message);
}
log.error('within log');
```